# Sorting by WEEKNUM When Dates Span 2 Years

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, gantt

**BACKGROUND**

1. I am using the following formula to produce a dynamic Gantt chart in Excel 2019.

```
=IF(AND(FM$8>=$H10,FM$8<=$I10,$P10="Not Started"),"R",IF(AND(FM$8>=$H10,FM$8<=$I10,$P10="In Progress"),"P",IF(AND(FM$8>=$H10,FM$8<=$I10,$P10="Completed"),"C","")))
```

2. I use conditional formatting for each letter (R=Red, P=Blue, C=Green) to create each bar in the chart (as shown).

[image: Screenshot of Gantt chart]

3. I used WEEKNUM to populate the Week Start and Week End columns. I want to use the formula above to produce a Gantt chart that uses the WEEKNUM data. *Instead of Jan 01, 2020 for my first Gantt chart column, I would have W1, W2, and so on. However, I'm using dates that span 2 years and I'm not sure how to sort columns properly, as I would get 1 (2020) and 1 (2021) as the top values.*

**QUESTION**

Given that I'm using dates that span 2 years, is there any way I can use the WEEKNUM data to sequence the tasks properly in this dynamic Gantt chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either add a new column showing YearWeek, or convert your existing columns.

It can be any format your prefer, but I would recommend:

```
=YEAR(A2)&"W"&WEEKNUM(A2)
```

By putting the year first, weeks in 2021 will come after weeks in 2020.

[image]

Comment: But how to make Chart , since needs numeric data.  Data in column D doesn't suitable for most of charts !!

Comment: OP is using conditional formatting to color cells as if they were a Gantt chart.

Comment: The OP want's  *I can use the WEEKNUM data to sequence the tasks properly in this dynamic Gantt chart?*

Comment: The tasks are on the rows of the spreadsheet. The post title mentions sorting. Sequence in this context is a synonym for sort. The weeknum will be used in the conditional formatting. These are sortable alphanumerically.

Comment: Sorting is not the issue,,, but is to use WEEKNUM , making the Chart.

Comment: It's not an actual chart. It's conditionally formatted cells acting as a gantt chart.

Comment: I don't have a reputation of ≥15 [https://superuser.com/help/self-answer], so if I found an answer that works, what should I do?

Comment: I believe you just add a new answer to the question.

Comment: @Owen Do you think this formula works just as well? `=YEAR(A2)&TEXT(WEEKNUM(A2),"00")`.

Comment: Looks like it. You might also try `=YEAR(A2)*100+WEEKNUM(A2)`. This will mean it's formatted as a number.